# Can observer listen on another thread in NSNotification in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios8

I went through the Apple doc and got to understand that we should have notification and observer on same thread but when i see the Apple threaded core data example parser operation is sending notification from thread other than main thread but observer is on main thread. I got confused about it or I am missing something here.

Comment: There are two post notification calls in APLParseOperation.m which one are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to any one of the two notification calls in `APLParseOperation.m` of Apple's [ThreadedCoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html) sample.

The relevant bits are:

**Notification #1**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:APLParseOperation.AddEarthQuakesNotificationName
                                                    object:self
                                                 userInfo:@{APLParseOperation.EarthquakeResultsKey: earthquakes}];
```

The observer for this is:

```
// In APLEarthQuakeSource.m
_addEarthQuakesObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:APLParseOperation.AddEarthQuakesNotificationName
                                                                            object:nil
                                                                             queue:nil
                                                                        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
    /**
```

This is fine because of the `nil` parameter for `queue`.   According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:), if you pass `nil` for this parameter, the "*block is run synchronously on the posting thread*."   All good.

**Notification #2**

The next notification,

```
- (void)handleEarthquakesError:(NSError *)parseError {

    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:APLParseOperation.EarthquakesErrorNotificationName
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:@{APLParseOperation.EarthquakesMessageErrorKey: parseError}];
}
```

always gets called on the main thread:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleEarthquakesError:) withObject:parseError waitUntilDone:NO];
```

'Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I guess I was not able to relate passing nil parameter will make run thread synchronously on current thread so make sense as we are on same thread. Am I correct?

Comment: @manismku: Yes, that's all there is to it.   'Glad to have helped.  Please accept the answer if you're happy.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted your answer but since I am new so score cant be displayed publicly.

Comment: @manismku: welcome to stackoverflow and congratulations on your first post. New users should be able to accept answers.  Here's some [information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on how to accept an answer.